# Android Text View And Edit Text Visible On Button Click

Tags: android

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="Contact" />
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Home"/>
            <EditText
                android:textSize="@dimen/bootstrap_button_default_font_size"
                android:id="@+id/edithome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mobile"/>
            <EditText
                android:textSize="@dimen/bootstrap_button_default_font_size"
                android:id="@+id/editmobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Work"/>
            <EditText
                android:textSize="@dimen/bootstrap_button_default_font_size"
                android:id="@+id/editwork"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />
```

1. This is my Layout with one Button and Text View and Edit Text.
2. My requirement is initially the text view and edit text are invisible.
3. When ever the button is clicked then only it should show.
4. Can anyone help me doing this.
5. I'm new to android.
6. Thanks in Advance. [This is what I want when the Button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kddrB.png)

Comment: onButtonclick all u need is view.setVisibility(View.Visible);

Comment: Post your code whatever you have tried till.

Comment: Also Rakesh android development is done using the language Java not javascript. Please change your questions tags from javascript to java. No offence, but javascript is used in html, etc. Please don't confuse it with Java.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming You have still done some coding until now. Then You simply can call on `buttonClick:`

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()){

@Override
public void onClick(View v){

  if(yourTextView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){

  yourTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

      }    
    }    
});
```

BUT, it´s important what Your goal is. If Your goal is to just make them invisible, this above is all You need for every view that should be invisible. But if You also want to reduce the blank space in Your layout, You should use:

```
yourTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The difference between `INVISIBLE` and `GONE` is, that `INVISIBLE` just makes the view invisible, but the taken place in the layout will left there. `GONE` makes the view invisible AND deletes the space in Your layout.

and if You want to switch that, say like a light, on/off, do :

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()){

@Override
public void onClick(View v){

  if(yourTextView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){

         yourTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

  }else{

         yourTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }    
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially you need to make all views which you want to hide as INVISIBLE and then inside the onClick() of your button, you can set visibility of the views to VISIBLE, for example:

```
anyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in your `xml` put visibility to `invisible` to these elements that you want , and in you java code on button click set to your `edittext` and `textview` this property:

```
edittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set gone/invisible in xml or while your screen is in front.

i.e on screen load you have to

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

than make it visible on button click

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            findViewById(R.id.textView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.editText).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your xml layout, in the textview and edittext set this parameter `android:visibility="invisible"` and then in your java code set

```
EditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
TextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```